# Altering demographics data that was responded incorrectly in a survey to be published in a journal

Tags: survey, social-science

Cross-posted (kind of) from [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/199501/changing-demographics-data-that-was-responded-incorrectly-in-a-survey-to-be-publ)

We have a research paper that we want to get published in a journal. The paper is some simple statistical analysis of a survey we made. One of the questions in the demographics section is "What is your profession?" and you are given 4 options plus "Other" where you can write whatever you want. In some cases, people wrote things in "Other" that qualified as one of the other 4 predetermined possible answers.

The survey was responded by personnel of some hospitals, and the recommendations about the wrong responses were noted from the hospitals' administration themselves reviewing the survey data.

The options where: Medical doctor, Nurse, Administrative Personnel, Technician, Other (free text).

Is it bad practice to change the results to refelct this? Can we do it and simply add a disclaimer that this was done and document what changes were made? Is it better if we just leave it as is?

Comment: If you have a systematic approach to adjusting the answers, you can do it and describe what you did.  If you do this sort of thing, do it before looking at responses to the other questions.

Answer (score 7):

Some data cleansing is almost always necessary, and this is a clear-cut case for it. And data cleansing always involves some level of subjectivity. Ideally, have this recoding done by two people independently, and wherever they disagree, have a conversation.

I would absolutely recommend [Azor Ahai's suggestion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/199511/4140): cleanse as you and he describe, and be explicit about what you did.

Answer (score 6):

It is sensible to recode your variables, as well explained by Stephan Kolassa's answer and Henry's comment, as long as you document the process and keep everything very explicit. You may also want to check if these "other" answers reflect some sort of concern or disagreement of the respondents with your suggested categories.

For example, the respondents might feel that these categories fail to capture some differences (important to their eyes), like skill, paycheck, or job difficulty. For example, consider the difference between a secretary intern and an administrator, who would be both classified under the "administrative" umbrella. Respondents answering "other" (while they should check another option) might want to draw attention to this kind of issue.

This can be a valid concern from a statistical point of view, as it may hint to an [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) or [other model misspecification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model_specification) issue, depending on your research question. It is not necessarily the case, but this is something worth investigating - if you haven't already.

It might also hint to a problem with the question [validity](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3205040), which is a point reviewers may raise. So be prepared to justify the way the question was asked.

These potential issues do not prevent you from recoding the answers (which, again, is a sensible thing to do), but you should document your recoding choices and explain why they are justified relative to your research question. If some respondents indeed disagree with your profession nomenclature, it is worth documenting, so future studies on the subject can take it into account and improve future instances of this question.